# How to use for loop multiple condition in switch case different condition using chunk split in Php

Tags: php, curl, reference, string-length

**PHP**

As you know below code PHP I am trying to get increase the string length when the string length is more the 6700 char it will be split chunk am using switch case condition chunk is working while am doing loop it's not working it's going timeout after the 6700 for looping is not working please try to help me in looping to in switch case if length more than 6700 chare use another case condition

```
$string_length = strlen($pass_string1);
    print_r($string_length);

    echo "<br/>";



      switch ($string_length) //10000 char 
     {

        case ($string_length > 0 && $string_length < 14000):
          $parts = ceil($string_length / 2); // Break string into 2 parts
          $str_chunks = chunk_split($pass_string1, $parts);
       
          
          break;
        
        case ($string_length > 14000 && $string_length < 21000):
          $parts = ceil($string_length / 3); // Break string into 3 parts
          $str_chunks = chunk_split($pass_string1, $parts);
         
      
          break;
        
        case ($string_length > 21000 && $string_length < 28000):
          $parts = ceil($string_length / 4); // Break string into 4 parts
          $str_chunks = chunk_split($pass_string1, $parts);
         
        
          break;
        
        default: 
          $parts = ceil($string_length/ 10); // Break string into 10 parts
          $str_chunks = chunk_split($pass_string1, $parts);
          
         
          break;

      }

    
   
    $string_array = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL,$str_chunks));
      

    

    for($i=0;$i<count($string_array);$i++) 

   {

      
      $enc_str = implode('',$string_array);
      $enc_str3 = urlencode($enc_str);
    
      echo "Convert of character : ".strlen($enc_str3)."<br/>";   
      // $substr = substr($enc_str3,0,7650);
   }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? What doesn't work? How is 6700 chars related, doesn't seem to be used anywhere? Why not just use `chunk_split($pass_string1, 6700)` to split into 6700chars long chunks? (fyi, `,` and `.` exist, little hard to read without punctuation)

Comment: hello sir it's my string length more than 20000  last exceed 6700 after 6700 it's going time out I use like how you told me but it's no use looping not working because i need to translate 20000 char it just translates only 6700 please try to help me

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't use `chunk_split` for this, but [str_​split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) instead. This will give you an array of strings you can easily loop over

Comment: I used both sir str split also not looping

Comment: What do you mean "_not looping_"? Be a little more descriptive in your "error" descriptions, it's a little hard for me to understand exactly what you are trying to do. str_split returns an array, use [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over the items.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Good luck

Comment: You don't put conditions in `case`. `case` is followed by a single value that's compared to the `switch()` expression.

Comment: If you want to test a series of conditions, use `if` and `elseif`.

Comment: But you could use `switch(ceil($string_length / 7000))` and then you'll have single values that you can compare with in `case`.

Comment: can u help me how like simple code I use  if the condition it's  not working  so I used to switch case

Comment: it's not working sir

Comment: Are you trying to split a string then urlencode it...then show how many characters each split have? Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes sirI want to increase the string length character for translate to string language translation am using URL encode and Systran API i am struck on looping and splitting because after 6700 string length timeout it's not translateing string just time out